# Compare stored values in Selenium IDE

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-ide

I am new to test automation and to Selenium IDE. With Selenium IDE, I want to store two values(integer) and compare them. Test passes if the compared result is greater than or equal to zero. So far, I only found an option to store the values and wondering if there is any option to compare the stored values. 
Any suggestion would be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Are you comparing the values to each other, or just to verify each is not a negative number?

Comment: @Klendathu I am comparing the the values to each other. In other words, difference must be zero or greater than that.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.  Are you say, taking number A, and comparing it to number B, and test is successful if A is greater than or equal to B?  I mean, if I take any random numbers, say, 2 and 4, if I subtract 2 from 4, the difference will be positive, and pass the test. but if I subtract 4 from 2, then the difference is negative, failing the test.

Comment: @Klendathu Let's say I take a number A which is 2 and then take a number B which is 4,. Then I ''always'' subtract A from B. If the result is zero or positive then the test passes, otherwise it fails. I hope this is clear to you.

Comment: okay, so regardless of the value of the numbers, you're always subtracting A from B?

Comment: @Klendathu Actually value of A remains same and only the value of B might change everytime when a test is run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, assuming you're always subtracting A (constant value) from B(variable value), you can use some javascript to perform the test.

```
store | 2 | A
store | 4 | B 
storeEval | var s = false; s = eval((storedVars['B'] - storedVars['A']) >=0); | s
verifyExpression | ${s}
```

replace the two store steps above with whatever you use to get your variables A and B.

The verifyExpression line will pass(return true) if result is greater than or equal to zero, will fail(stay false) if not.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware that i could use Javascript commands in Selenium IDE as well. I tried what you said and I got '[error] Actual value 'True' did not match' when B-A >=0 and '[error] Actual value 'False' did not match' when B-A<0.

Comment: Hmm, can you show me exactly what you have in the IDE?  I ran those lines with a variety of values and they all worked.

Comment: @kklendathu I have same as you suggested. 
store | 2 | A
store | 4 | B 
storeEval | var s = false; s = eval((storedVars['B'] - storedVars['A']) >=0); | s
verifyExpression | ${s} 

I am not sure where it went wrong.

Comment: Weird.  What version of Firefox and Selenium IDE do you have/?

Answer (score 1):

```
store |2| A
store |4| B
storeEval |var s = false; s = eval((storedVars['B'] - storedVars['A']) >=0);| s
echo |${s}|
```

---

```
Executing: |store | 2 | A |
Executing: |store | 4 | B |
Executing: |storeEval | var s = false; s = eval((storedVars['B'] - storedVars['A']) >=0); | s |
script is: var s = false; s = eval((storedVars['B'] - storedVars['A']) >=0);
Executing: |echo | ${s} | |
echo: true
Test case passed
```